# How to convert Class<str> to Class<dict>

Tags: python, dictionary, amazon-dynamodb

I need to upload some items in DynamoDB. I am using `boto3` resource for the same. The item I need to insert are a couple of `JSON` strings dumped together. I need to convert them to `dict` so I can insert them in DynamoDB.

```py
def update_record_Dynamo(
    company_name,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    status,
    phone):
    
    table_name = "cpe-uat-ddb-cem-newpro"
    table = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table(table_name)
    
    response = table.get_item(Key={'company': company_name})
    
    existing_user = response['Item']['users']

    # user looks like this = 
    '''
    {
        "first_name": "bala",
        "last_name": "Reaburn",
        "email": "b1010gmail.com",
        "phone": "9053258111",
        "status": "administrator"
    }
    '''
        
    flag = {
        "first_name": first_name,
        "last_name": last_name,
        "email": email,
        "phone": phone,
        "status": status
    }
    
    flag_dict = json.dumps([existing_user, flag])
    # new_users = jam+flag
    # new_users = json.loads(flag_dict)
    
    flag_dict = json.dumps(flag_dict)
    flag_dict = json.loads(flag_dict)
    
    final = json.dumps(eval(str(flag_dict)))
    print(type(final))
    
    update_record_response = table.update_item(
        Key={'company': company_name},
        AttributeUpdates={
            'users': final,
            },
        )
    
    return update_record_response
```

This is the error I get:

```py
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter AttributeUpdates.users, value: [
{
    "last_name": "",
    "first_name": "",
    "email": "",
    "status": ""
}
, 
{
    "first_name": "bala",
    "last_name": "Reaburn",
    "email": "b1010gmail.com",
    "phone": "9053258688",
    "status": "administrator"
}
], type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
Invalid type for parameter AttributeUpdates.users, value: [{"last_name": "", "first_name": "", "email": "", "status": ""}, {"first_name": "bala", "last_name": "Reaburn", "email": "b1010gmail.com", "phone": "9053258688", "status": "administrator"}], type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're uploading it as a list of dictionaries, instead of dictionaries themselves.

`flag_dict = json.dumps([existing_user, flag])`

Creates the list, and you can see in the error that comes back that it still has the brackets around it. You'll want to recreate it as a dictionary of dictionaries if you want it in that style.

Edit: To rewrite the line above try

```
flag_dict = {
             'existing_user': existing_user,
             'flag': flag
             }
```

Edit 2:

```
flag = {"first_name":first_name, "last_name":last_name, "email":email,"phone":phone, "status":status}
    
final = {
         'existing_user': existing_user,
         'flag': flag
         } 
    
update_record_response = table.update_item(
        Key={'company': company_name},
        AttributeUpdates={
            'users': final,
            },
        )
    
    return update_record_response
```

Comment: type of final is <class 'str'>

Comment: @bhargavpatel Yeah if you want a dict then I would replace the line as above, and delete the rest, then try uploading it. That should be in a dictionary format. I'll make an edit above.

Comment: Doint that gives me following errors :

Comment: Unknown parameter in AttributeUpdates.users: "existing_user", must be one of: Value, Action ;

Comment: Unknown parameter in AttributeUpdates.users: "flag", must be one of: Value, Action

Comment: Is the users attribute a map or a string? If it's a map I think it'll take a dictionary upload. I usually use json.dumps to turn my dictionaries into strings and upload them to a string attribute.